# getting Sum of duplicate values when load to crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have two tables call finish goods and return goods. 
finish goods has columns Item, finish_qty and Damage_qty

return goods has Item and return_damage_qty

I have two records in finish goods as follows. 
Tuna, 100, 30
Jack, 200,0

And return goods has another two records as follows.
Tuna, 30
Tuna, 0

I want to get the sum of Damage tuna in crystal reports. 
I have created crystal reports by getting the Item by item table, and sum of the damage qty by formula. 
sum in damage tuna should be 60 but it displays 90 as output. which is doubling the finish good values. 
please help.

Comment: can you update the question with your sql query?

Comment: can you show your report structure?

Comment: if you are calling the two tables in the same report you can create a formula by calling the objects of these different tables e.g : {table1.column} + {table2.column} or by drag and drop columns from report feilds, else if you are not calling both in the report you will have to calculate it from DB in your SP